# How to communicate between Flask and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

everyone. So i've been going through this documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/. I have a Flask site up and running, but, when i try to set up what they have, i just get the error: 
   `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_numbers?a=5&b=5 404 (NOT FOUND)`

It just appears that the client can't even establish the connection with the server.

The only thing that differs on my side is how i assign values to the vars a and b. I've also made sure to include the script defining what $SCRIPT_ROOT is. Not sure what to do here. I also have jQuery properly loaded.

I was thinking about trying ajax, but i couldnt find a good example of ajax with python. (i'm pretty new to back end development)

```
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/add_numbers', {
            a: 5,
            b: 5
        }, function(data) {                                 
            alert(data.result);
        });
```

basically, the whole point of what im trying to do is to eventually get data from a database into my javascript. I've managed to get data from my database into my HTML, but not into my JS yet. Thats what im trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` *is* AJAX, it's just wrapped up nice and cleanly. Anyway, if you're using the server-side code from the article, then your JavaScript code has the wrong URL: you should be using `$SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers'` with an `_` before `add_numbers`.

Anyway, if you've got all the data in the HTML already, why not have the JavaScript extract the data from the HTML?

Comment: actually i was using the underscore. i must have copied a version from when i tried not using it in both places. When i had the matching underscores, i still got the same error. That's a good idea, icktoofay - to extract it from the html. I would just really like to understand how to use ajax and python properly, as i'd be using it again, im sure.

Comment: @jumpReturn: I'm not entirely sure why you're getting that error — the fact that you see a `GET ... 404` at all indicates that it's getting sent correctly, but Flask isn't routing it to the right place.

Comment: ef. it turns out i was missing the underscore somewhere. sorry. ;( thanks for the help, guys.